# How to make all textareas on a website "readonly"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a lot of textareas on my website but they aren't read-only and it would take a lot of time to add the `readonly` attribute to all of them. Is there any other way to make them all read-only?

Comment: Have you tried something?? If yes, Post your effort.

Comment: What's the point of having `<textarea>` elements on your page that can't be used?

Comment: Do you need to use textarea? They are generally more designed for forms.

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? Please read up on providing a [mcve].

Comment: i use $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
});

Answer (score 2):

You *could* * use JavaScript to select all the `textarea`s on a page and loop through the collection, setting the `readonly` attribute to `true`.

```js
/** ES6 VERSION **/
{
  let textareas=document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"),
      x=textareas.length;
  while(x--)
    textareas[x].readOnly=1;
}
/** ES5 VERSION
(function(){
  var textareas=document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"),
      x=textareas.length;
  while(x--)
    textareas[x].readOnly=1;
})();
**/
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
```

`*` I say *could* because all anyone would have to do is disable JavaScript in their browser in order to get around this. The better solution would be to "manually" set the `readonly` attribute of each `textarea` in your code, although, anyone who truly wants to circumvent that could still do so through their browser's dev. console.

Comment: Agreed. If the point is to prevent the data from changing on submission the best solution would be to handle it on the server side.

Comment: Indeed. I felt that was beyond the scope of the question, though. But feel free to edit it in if you think it should be included.

Answer (score 1):

With VanillaJS you could use this code:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].readOnly = true;
}
```

With jQuery:

```
$('textarea').attr('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just put a fieldset around all your textareas elements and disable the fieldset:

```js
var myFieldset = document.getElementById("fieldset");
disableAll.onclick = function () { myFieldset.disabled = true; }
enableAll.onclick = function () { myFieldset.disabled = false; }
```

```html
<button id="disableAll">Disable all</button>
<button id="enableAll">Enable all</button>

<form>
    <fieldset id="fieldset">
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="sample text"/>
        </div>
        <div><textarea>your textarea</textarea></div>
        <div><input type="button" value="a button"/></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Using jQuery you could use something like:

```
$('input[type=text], textarea').attr('readonly', true);
```